# Does CsvHelper GetRecords() actually instantiate objects?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using CsvHelper to read data from .csv file.

My code :

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture){ HasHeaderRecord = true };
using (var textreader = new StreamReader(filepath))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(textreader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Vehicle>();                   
    foreach(var vehicle in records)
    {
        vehicles.Add(vehicle);
    }
}
```

At which moment is the object actually created ?

Comment: See [Reading a CSV File](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file): *The `GetRecords<T>` method will return an `IEnumerable<T>` that will yield records. What this means is that only a single record is returned at a time as you iterate the records.*  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Incidentally, you're not actually using `config` despite having allocated it.  Did you mean to pass it into the `CsvReader` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

It creates a delegate using expression trees to instantiate the object based on your config and mapping settings.

As @dbc stated, `GetRecords<T>` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` that will yield records. That means only a single record is created and returned on each iteration of the `IEnumerable<T>`.

If you were to project the records using something like `ToList()`, that would create an object for every record and your entire file would be in memory.

Comment: Hello Mr Close, thank you for your answer, much appreciated. Indeed It does run well at this time on my computer. I am able to write AND read csv files. Thank you for your work on CsvHelper, I am still looking in it to get the most of it.